# get file names from uploadify jquery plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

that is my first post

I am trying here, to get the names of the files that are uploaded, so that the user can delete it if desired, the same way as yahoo.

`$("#uploadifysub1").uploadify({
            'uploader'       : 'JS/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : 'JS/uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg'      : 'cancel.png',
            'buttonImg'      : 'attach.png',
            'folder'         : 'uploads',
            'queueID'        : 'divquickuploadProgress1',
            'auto'           : true,
            'multi'          : true
        });`

the problem is that I cannot get files names, any suggestions?

is there any function in uploadify, that can remove an uploaded file, or I have to do that myself??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean before they are actually uploaded? Remove them from the upload queue, right?

Comment: no after they actually uploaded, there are option in uplodify, I think (closeimage) or some thing like that, that enables me to delete them while uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from uploadify

> **fileDataName**
>
> The name of your files array in the
>   upload server script. Default =
>   ‘Filedata’

PHP code

```
$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Do I have to make an ajax request to get that value?
and $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']; contains the name of last uploaded file, right??

Comment: To get that value you only need to "echo" in php. catch it with "onComplete" in uploadify. See uploadify documentation on "onComplete", the parameter "response".

Comment: thanks alot that was a great help, I want to vote up but I cannot right now, again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

thanks to "Codler", I could solve this problem, I will share the code, maybe it will help.

```
$("#uploadifysub1").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'JS/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'JS/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'      : 'cancel.png',
        'buttonImg'      : 'attach.png',
        'folder'         : 'uploads',
        'queueID'        : 'divquickuploadProgress1',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : true,
        'onComplete'     : function(event, queueID, fileObj, reposnse, data) {
            // write your own implementation
                           }
    });
```

my implementation was like that

```
var cod = '<tr>';
cod += '<td align="left">'+fileObj.name+'</td>';
cod += '<td align="left">';
cod += '<span onclick="removeprev(this,'+fileObj.name+')" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;';
cod += '[remove]</span>';
cod += '</td>';
cod += '</tr>';
$('#uploaded_files').append(cod);
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

why didn't you just set the removeCompleted option to false. It queues all the uploaded files.