# Having issues sending upload values to hidden field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

i have been trying so hard to fix my issue. I've looked on google loads and attempted the fixes but i am having no luck at all.

```
$(function() {
    $("#listing_pic").uploadify({
        height        : 30,
        swf           : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        uploader      : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
        width         : 120,
        fileExt       : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.JPEG;',
        checkExisting : 'uploadify/check-exists.php',
        simUploadLimit: 2,
        fileSizeLimit : '4MB',
        auto          : true,
        multi         : true,
        onComplete    : function(event,queueID,fileObj,response,data) {
            $('#hiddenlistingpic').val(response);
        },
    });
});
```

Im trying to get Uploadify to upload my image to my server (which works fine) but then send the filename to the hidden field so that i can post the data into my database update class. It's giving me a headache, and im more than certain its a simple fix.

Comment: can you console.log( response + data )?

Comment: What is Your `uploadify/check-exists.php` return or echo value?

Comment: why not just update the database directly on the server-side upload script?

Comment: nothing wrong with the check-exists.php, its just not putting the value into the hidden field like it should. and im v confused lol.

and that_guy that's what im trying to do, but i need the values of the uploaded for it to work. Its a profile update script that im working on

Comment: i mean since you can access the file via the uploadify.php file, why not update the database from that script as well, then you wouldn't need hidden field to do additional ajax request to update the db, if you aren't too concerned with separation, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466188/1253747

```
$(function() {
$("#listing_pic").uploadify({
    height        : 30,
    swf           : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    uploader      : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    width         : 120,
    fileExt       : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.JPEG;',
    checkExisting : 'uploadify/check-exists.php',
    simUploadLimit: 2,
    fileSizeLimit : '4MB',
    auto          : true,
    multi         : true,
    onComplete    : function(event,queueID,fileObj,response,data) {
        $('#hiddenlistingpic').val(fileObj.name);
    },
});
});
```

or from the uploadify docs, there seems to be many other ways to get it:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        $('#hiddenlistingpic').val(file.name);
    }
```

same thing can be done with the `onuploadcomplete`.
or is there anything else that i am missing?

Comment: onUploadSuccess was the version i needed. Cheers buddy, knew it was simple!