# Get file names from uploadify queue BEFORE uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440295/get-file-names-from-uploadify-jquery-plugin).

I'm trying to get the file names from the upload queue before uploading, so I can show those names in a form.
Checking on the documentation they talk a lot on how to manage such information after uploading, but I can't find how to do it before.

Already tried to get access to the input that it think the script uses, with `$('#file_upload').val()` but anyhow I got an empty value even after selecting some files.

Comment: Show your code and some markup and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the [onSelect](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onselect/) event?

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
    'swf'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'onSelect' : function(file) {
        alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was added to the queue.');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm feeling so dumb for not trying this event before, thank you.

Comment: @Isaias Don't worry - glad to help!